# Something like checkdsk for ubuntu 14.04 LTS server?

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, hard-drive

I have a server with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on it. Past week the harddisk was acting up and they had to change the harddisk with a new one.

I know there is for windows a command like checkdsk. Is there a simular command/program for ubuntu, so I can run that command/program and check the harddisk for errors via SSH?

Comment: You might be looking for `fsck` - *check and repair a Linux filesystem*

Comment: Do you have hard console access?